# Application event when screen becomes active

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a NSTimer that I create when entering method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

When entering method `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` I say `[timer invalidate]; timer = nil;`

When entering method `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` I create the timer again. This works when the user has pressed the home button and then runs the application again.
However if my screen gets inactive because of user inactivity when inside the app, then becomes active and then automatically enters the application again, the timer will not work.
Therefore I am wondering what method is accessed when the application re-enters from an inactive screen.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method instead of `applicationWillEnterForeground:`.

Comment: Yes thank you. But the problem still arises, the application does not enter applicationDidBecomeActive either when it starts from screen activation.

Comment: It should. Actually, I just tested it, and it does. Have you typed the method name correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Tried these?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

The other case you may want to investigate is when a phone call comes in (or an SMS message alert is presented).